# Box change depending on drop-down list validation

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

For this example, we will use the top line of data so...

```
Type = H6 
Time Depart = I6
Time landed = J6
Single Engine In Command = K6
Single Engine Dual = L6
```

My plan is to add `I6` and `J6` into `L6` if `H6` says Dual.
But `I6` to add with `J6` into K6 if `H6` says In Command.

Can anyone help me with my boxes? In `L6` I already have the formula (to make box blank if no values in `I6` & `J6`;

```
=IF(AND(I6<>"", J6<>""), J6-I6, )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IF((I6:I<>"") * (J6:J<>"") * (H6:H=K$5), TEXT(J6:J-I6:I, "hh:mm"), ), 
               IF((I6:I<>"") * (J6:J<>"") * (H6:H=L$5), TEXT(J6:J-I6:I, "hh:mm"), )})
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K6SXthYfcOyEvzMSYpElkCLeaASzZ0p3ANXyUYfrFjs/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: Could you share your email so I can share this with you? When copying and Pasting it doesn't seem to work...

Then you will see where I have gone wrong

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eopYwHUO37ZrgZPczf5mMwH-FyUgCHndXptU18WsX-M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you need to delete L6:L10

Comment: Got it! Thanks again for your time! +1